# How to parse an Auditbeat "event.type" in Logstash?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I have an almost-default installation of Auditbeat on several of my hosts, that are also auditing changes of `/etc`, that forward log data to a Logstash instance elsewhere. I want to generate a message based on these logs, as by default Auditbeat does not fill the `message` field with value (they moved it to `event.original` and anyway it's disabled, and I want to be as close to production as possible with my configs), so that Kibana displays "failed to find message" when I try viewing logs from `auditbeat-*`. So I went to parsing and adding fields to events with Logstash.

I have encountered an interesting issue: If I query something that belongs to any custom tree under root in JSON but `event`, Logstash filters work, but should I decide to query `[event][type]`, the result is always false. The problem is, if I just stuff `"%{[event][type]}"` into my message, the value is in there! I have tried `if ([event][type] == "info") {...}`, `if ([type] == "info")` and also tried `if ([event][action] == "change")` to no avail, while when I do output a debug message value with `"%{[event][type]} %{[event][action]}"` both values are present and equal to whatever I'm comparing to. Note that `[event][module]` filter actually works, so this behavior with `[event][type]` really baffles me.

So, how to filter based on `[event][type]` in Logstash, provided they are present in incoming data?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was pretty simple. Both `event.type` and `event.action` are arrays and not strings, so comparing an array to a string returned false. The proper way of filtering through these is using "in", like this:

```
if "info" in [event][type] {...}
```